# How to make Ink effect fill all the space in a BottomNavigationBarItem

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm making a simple Flutter app with a BottomNavigationBar and the label in my BottomNavigationBarItem exceeds the ink effect created when I tap on it . For some reason, it seems to be covering the icon only and not the label as well.

[image]

How can I change this behavior to accommodate the label as well? I would also prefer to have a more rectangular shape for the ink reaction.

Edit:

My code for the navigation bar

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.blue[900],
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.black87,
    onTap: onTabTapped,
    showUnselectedLabels: true,
    currentIndex: _currentIndex,
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.collections),
        title: Text('Collections'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
        title: Text('Recent'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
        title: Text('More'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

[Current Behavior](https://gfycat.com/leftsparsecatfish)

[Expected Behavior](https://gfycat.com/wastefulamusingdamselfly)

Comment: Hi. It seems that you are new to stackoverflow. People are likely to downvote your question if you don't elaborate it properly. If you provide the code that you are talking about, your question would be better. Read the guide about how to ask questions if you don't know what i'm talking about. :)

Comment: try to use BottomAppBar instead of BottoNavigationBar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling around with the flutter standard library, I now realised that `BottomNavigationBarItem` isn't a widget, but a container class to encapsulate the information that `BottomNavigationBar` need for its items.

Unfortunately, you will need to override `BottomNavigationBar` and create your own `CustomBottomNavigationBar` to do what you want.

The good news is that this is incredibly easy, since you only have to change one line of code. :)

I copied the code from `$FLUTTER_HOME/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar.dart` and made only one adjustment: at line 480, I changed `InkResponse` to `InkWell` and now it works as you wished.

With `InkResponse`:

[image]

With `InkWell`:

[image]

I suggest you to create an override folder in your project with the overridden classes, this is how I do it (I have overridden the default bottom sheet class):
[image]

Then, you can just import your overridden classes like this:

```
import 'package:your_project/widgets/override/bottom_navigation_bar.dart' as BottomNavigationBarOverride;
```

And use it like so:

```
  bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBarOverride.BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.blue[900],
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.black87,
    onTap: onTabTapped,
    showUnselectedLabels: true,
    currentIndex: _currentIndex,
    items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.collections),
        title: Text('Collections'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.phone),
        title: Text('Recent'),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.more_horiz),
        title: Text('More'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

## Old response

If you provide more code, I could help you out more.

Judging by the picture that you provided, this is intended behavior as bottom navigation itens aren't intended to be large. They are intend to be swift and clean as the [material spec](https://material.io/components/bottom-navigation) suggests:

[image]
[image]

If you intend to make only one "option", I suggest that you change your widget to a [FlatButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FlatButton-class.html). But be warned, this is against the spec as, for usability purposes, bottom navigation itens should contain at least 3 options and at max 5 options.

Comment: I actually have 4 options. I have edited the post to include my sample code. I simply wanted the ink splash effect to span the whole BottomNavigationBarItem when clicked, not just a circle around the icon.

Comment: Thanks! That’s exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

After a few tries I figured that changing `splashFactory` could do the trick.

```
MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(
    splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory,
  ),
)
```